# Understand when qthread finish

Tags: qt, pyqt, qthread

I study Qthread. I'm confuse when qthread emit signal finished. Is signal finished emited when exit on run function?

```
class TestThread(QtCore.QThread):
         customSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(['QString'])

         def __init__(self):
            QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

         def run(self):
            print 'some code in run functions... '
            self.customSignal.emit('OK')
            print 'after this istruction qthread emit instantly finished signal?'
```

In run function I emit my custom signal that is intercepted by other class.In other class I receive a signal and I also check if Qthread is runnig:

```
     print 'TestThread is running? - ', self.myTestTh.isRunning()
```

and sometimes it print True!!!
So, it seems that Qthread not finish instantly when exit on run function
So, Can I intercept also a finished signal to be sure that Qthread is not running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QThread as a `finished()` signal that you can listen to if you want to be notified when the thread actually quits.

Also you can do something like this:

```
myThread.quit();
myThread.wait();
```

where the call to `wait()` will block until your thread as properly finished.

Comment: can i use `myThread.finished.connect(self.method)` to execute a event for Ui to updated after a thread finishes.